# the machine level represent of signed and unsigned integer

Tags: c++

Am i correct to say follows:

- the variable of `unsigned int` take the whole 32 bits to represent a non-negative integer use two's complement. So the range of integer it can hold is from 0 to (2^32) - 1.
- the variable of `int` take the whole 32 bits to represent a integer use two's complement. So the range of integer it can hold is from -(2^31) to (2^31) - 1.

e, i say that in the situation of a machine which word size is 32bits.

Comment: Neither of those is correct.

Comment: It is correct if int is 32 bit on your architecture?

Comment: Unsigned doesn't use two's complement encoding.  No need.

Comment: `signed int` can be in sign and magnitude, one's complement or two's complement. `signed int` doesn't have to be 32 bits, but even if it is, not all 32 bits have to be for the integer's value.

Comment: For that matter not all the bits *have* to be used in `unsigned int` either.

Answer (score 6):

It is probably so most of the time. However the C standard only requires `int` to be a signed integer at least 16 bits in size and `unsigned int` to be an unsigned integer at least 16 bits in size.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Especially:

> The type int should be the integer type that the target processor is most efficient working with. This allows great flexibility: for example, all types can be 64-bit. However, several different integer width schemes (data models) are popular. This is because the data model defines how different programs communicate, a uniform data model is used within a given operating system application interface.